# How to change the default soap header?

Tags: php, soap-client

I am using this code to set the header.

```
$root = new \SimpleXMLElement('<S:Header/>');
```

and I get this error.

SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): namespace error : Namespace prefix S on Header is not defined.

Does anybody know How to solve this? :/ Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define namespace for prefix S.

```
$root = new SimpleXMLElement('<S:Header></S:Header>', LIBXML_NOERROR, false, 'S', true);
//add namespace attribute into root element
$root->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns:S','mynamespace');

print_r($root->asXML());
```

Comment: actually now I am not getting an error but when I dump the root variable to see if the header is added it is returning a null array.

Comment: dump `$root->asXML()` to preview xml created.